# How to calculate the sum of all input fields in HTML table column and display the value in a cell?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I need to sum all the input fields in each column in the table and reflect the sum of each column in the cell that is under each column and then sum these cells and show their result in the cell labeled 'Sum of Quarters' Total'.

I have a JQuery for calculating the numbers but it doesn't work with me and I don't know how to sum the total of each Quarter column and display it in the cell underneath it. Could you please help me with this? How can I show the total of each column? And how can I sum the total of these columns into one cell?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Exercise</th>
                    <th>Q1</th>
                    <th>Q2</th>
                    <th>Q3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Exercise #1</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Exercise #2</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="txt input-mini" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span5">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <label>Sum of Quarters' Total</label>
                    <input id="sum" type="text" class="input-medium" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span7">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <label>Quarters' Total</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                    <input type="text" class="input-mini" />
                    <input type="text" class="input-mini" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
            //handler to trigger sum event
            $(".txt").each(function () {
                $(this).keyup(function () {
                    calculateSum();
                });
            });
        });

        function calculateSum() {
            var sum = 0;
            //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
            $(".txt").each(function () {
                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }
            });

            //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
            $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
        }
    </script>
```

And this is a snapshot of the issue:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/gk5kyc7w/1/

For total just change

```
$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

to

```
$("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

For quarters:

```
    var sumQ = [];
    for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        sumQ[i] = 0;
        $('td:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').find(".txt").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sumQ[i] += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $(".span7").find('input').eq(i-1).val(sumQ[i].toFixed(2));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. Could you please explain to me your code regarding the sum of each quarter? I am a new to (and beginner in) JQuery and I need to understand this code.

Comment: i=1 => $('td:nth-child(2)') - every second cell in each row, then find ".txt" inside, and sum.
i=1 => $(".span7").find('input').eq(0) - first input in .span7 (results row)

Comment: what about if I have so many rows? is it gonna work and calculate as many as rows I have?

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. One last thing, I added one column between Exercise column and Q1 column and this jquery didn't show the total of the first quarter in the cell underneath it directly. Could you please help me with this? Can we make this JQuery working regardless of the number of columns that will be added between Exercise column and Q1 column?

Comment: Add a class to the quarter inputs `<input type="text" class="txt input-mini q1" />` same for q2 and q3. Change `$('td:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').find(".txt")` to `$('.q'+i)`. Add a class for the results inputs `<input type="text" class="input-mini result_q1" />` same for q2 and q3. Change `$(".span7").find('input').eq(i-1)` to `$('.result_q'+i)`. http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/gk5kyc7w/2/

Answer (score 0):

Changed to this. Hope is what you want

```
function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".txt").each(function () {
            //add only if the value is number
            if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });

        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saoj0xv1/)

Comment: input text value in jQuery must be access this way.